# programmatically toolbar items not showing iOS swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I am trying to add barButtonItem programmatically to a toolbar but no item showing up except the toolbar it self only

my code so far:

```
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

items.append(
     UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: nil, action: nil)
)

self.navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
```

[image]

Comment: is `self.navigationController` set?

Comment: my app is embedded in navigationController

Comment: toolbar showing but items no

Comment: I've only ever done it using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: nil, action: nil)`

Comment: I want to add to the toolbar not to the navigationBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code everything is correct but the toolbarItems are empty.
So you should do this

```
self.toolbarItems = items
```

instead of

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
```

Comment: Yes exactly I figured this thanks  

self.setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you call this code, when you call this in your `init()` of your `UIViewController` subclass, the navigationController is not set yet. When you do it in your `viewDidLoad` however, it will be set.

Comment: When you `print()` the `self.navigationController`, you get a value?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to "set Items" (e.g with animation):

```
self.setToolbarItems(items, animated: true)
```